# Sign In with Apple: verify my domain not working

Tags: ios, verify, ios13, apple-sign-in

I was integrating **Sign in with Apple** in my mobile app. I followed the configuration steps provided in the developer portal and downloaded the *apple-developer-domain-association.txt*  file and placed it on my server at the given path.[image] Now the file is loading from web browser but I'm not able to verify my domain on Apple developer account. Its giving me an error message "*Verification failed for domain*".

Anyone got same issue? how to get verified sucessfully

Comment: check apple-developer-domain-association.txt rights  on server (must be readeable by others i.e. world)

Comment: @user3344236 yes! the text file is able to read from browser

Comment: It works also with https ?

Comment: @user3344236 yes

Comment: I had the same issue before. Tried to download the file again and found it is slightly different. After the file is updated on our server I started to get another error: `An unexpected error occurred. Please try again. If the problem persists, please contact Apple Developer Program Support. https://developer.apple.com/support` Contacted to support, but they haven't responded with any solution yet.

Comment: Exactly the same issue. Works on both http:// and https:// via the browser. Fails verification in exactly the same way. Did you get a fix? Apple support came back and said submit a TSI - but I'm not sure that's going to get it resolved as it isn't a code-level issue. TSI request submitted though. Let's see what they come back with.

Comment: Found a solution - see my answer below or @MTZ4's answer below.

Answer (score 5):

To verify domain to configure Sign in With Apple `apple-developer-domain-association.txt` file must be accessible publicly.

```
https://{YOUR_DOMAIN}/.well-known/apple-developer-domain-association.txt
```

Make sure

1. Domains and domains associated with email addresses must comply with Sender Policy Framework (SPF) standards.
2. Must be accessible via `https`. http doesn't work.
3. No redirect not even to `wwww`. Example url mentioned above must serve the `apple-developer-domain-association.txt` file without any redirects.

Hint: if you are serving `apple-developer-domain-association.txt` with `www` than you must register domain `www.{YOUR_DOMAIN}` white configuring sign in with apple configuration on developer.apple.com. To do that you have to make sure `www.{YOUR_DOMAIN}` is SPF compliance.

Comment: You could also check if `your site is SPF Compliant` with these free tools:
 
- https://www.dmarcanalyzer.com/spf/checker/

- https://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx

Comment: @Bilal : No domain verification required after June 2020. Apple have simplified the process.

Answer (score 2):

In continues and addition to @Bilal

A. If the domain is not SPF compliant you will be noted immediately when trying to add it in the developer portal

B. If you not sure whether your site is redirected yo can check it in http://www.redirect-checker.org/ or just use postman and disable 'Automatically follow redirects' option in the request settings

C. Apple require that your server must support the Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.2 protocol and one of the cipher suites listed below:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

For me the problem was the www redirect I had no clue our servers do that, my devops helped me solve this just for the verification.

Best solution IMO is just use your own relay microservice with a unique dedicated domain...

Comment: All seems fine except for the ciphers. Don't know how to solve this problem though. Using Cloudflare/AWS/S3. Any tip?

Comment: Upgrading Cloudflare to a paid plan (PRO $20/month) did the trick. All paid plans include the required ciphers.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @MTZ4's response (upvoted BTW because you nailed it), here is the process that I needed to work through, with some pointers to anyone else not quite as familiar with working through these types of problems.

In my case, I had CloudFlare dealing with both the DNS and TLS cipher certificates and Heroku serving the site.

The first step is determining whether your TLS provider serves the appropriate TLS ciphers required by Apple.

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

One of the easiest way's to do this is by using [SSL labs certificate checker](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). Simply enter your root domain and let the report run (takes a few minutes). In the report response, look for the section *Cipher Suites* and verify the TLS ciphers Apple wants are available. In the image below you can see them in orange and marked as weak.

You can ignore the *weak* status, this is because these ciphers do not use ephemeral keys and will not be used in TLS 1.3.

[image: SSL Labs Results]

If you want a more comprehensive test, install [NMAP](https://nmap.org/download.html) and then download the [ssl-enum-ciphers script](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssl-enum-ciphers.html). After installing NMAP and downloading the script, execute the script against your domain:

`nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 my-root-domain.com`

This produces a result set that looks like this:

[image: NMAP results]

Once again look for the *TLSv1.2* section and check your list of ciphers against Apple's list. If they are not present (they are missing in the image above), then that is where your problem lies.

So how to fix? Well there are a few options and it all depends upon your TLS provider, which may be your web host or may be your DNS host depending upon your configuration.

For us, we are using CloudFlare as our DNS provider. CloudFlare also provides the TLS ciphers. Because CloudFlare does not support the ciphers Apple requires (the NMAP image above) and they won't add them due to their security concerns about TLS 1.2 and moving to TLS 1.3, we had to disable CloudFlare's proxy service to allow the TLS certificates that were being provided by our hosting service (Heroku).

This turned out to be easy. Just logging into CloudFlare, going to the DNS entries and changing the traffic routing behavior (click the orange cloud to make it grey for verification, then click it again once verification is done). For more information see [CloudFlare's support page](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005138088-Load-Balancing-TTLs-and-Orange-vs-Grey-Cloud).

After doing this, Heroku was serving the TLS ciphers, which include the Apple required ones (as shown in the SSL Labs image above).

Ultimately whoever is serving your TLS ciphers must include the ones Apple needs. If your tests above don't show the correct ciphers, check your DNS/TLS service and your hosting provider to see if they support them. If they don't, then you may need to switch.

Finally, it is also worth noting that in Apple's developer portal, when you click the *download* button for the verification file, do not click it again! Each time you click the button, the verification file changes as it seems to be dynamically generated.

Just fix all the TLS issues, then log into the Apple developer portal, download the file, upload to your server and then verify.

I did end up working with Apple support on some of this and they are looking at adding some documentation to the verification page that states what ciphers are needed so others don't hit the same problems.

Comment: If I disable CloudFlare's proxy service I can't even access my website anymore. It's on AWS/S3. But I believe my problem is with the ciphers since I'm using Cloudflare. Don't know how to solve it though. Any tips?

Comment: Upgrading my plan on Cloudflare to PRO ($20/month) did the trick. Didn't need to change a single configuration on Cloudflare. Still using Flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running node js and express and had the issue because I bought a cheap SSL cert from Sectigo.
Here's what I did to fix it.

1. Check your SSL certificate for errors https://www.digicert.com/help/
2. I had to install an intermediate certificate. That solved the issue.
   If you perform the check in Safari, it won't give you a confirmation that the domain is verified.
   Instead, perform the check in Chrome and it will give you a confirmation.
3. Inspect the HTTP header coming back from your server. If it's a 301 Apple won't follow it. Instead, the verification file must be returned via 200 HTTP status code. The verification file I'm referring to is https://example.com/.well-known/apple-developer-domain-association.txt where example.com is your domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cloudflare free tier, upgrading to the PRO plan (currently $20/month) does the trick. All their paid plans include the required ciphers.

And of course, you can always cancel the plan after verifying and go back to free.